# What do I need to do to accept an array parameter in webservice?

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws, cxf

WS to make a web service. As parameters I am taking in two strings and an array of a objects whose type are a class in my project.

I have the webservice interface and implementation created  and it is similar to this:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getStuff")
@WebResult(name = "result")
 Mix getStuff(
    @WebParam(name = "string1") String one,
    @WebParam(name = "string2") String two,
    @WebParam(name = "stuff") Stuff[] stuff
);
```

I am returning an object of type Mix which is a class in my project and I am accepting an array of type Stuff which is another class in my project. Testing from java is not a problem however when someone else attempts to consume the service or I try to send in a request with soapUI the array is always coming in null. What do I need to do so whomever is consuming my service can correctly send in the array of type Stuff? Do I need to do some customization with JAXB?

Comment: The core issue was with the Stuff class. I forgot to include a default constructor which led to my issues. I did end up changing the code to a List as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JAXB2 uses lists and not arrays, so you should replace the signature to

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getStuff")
@WebResult(name = "result")
 Mix getStuff(
    @WebParam(name = "string1") String one,
    @WebParam(name = "string2") String two,
    @WebParam(name = "stuff") java.util.List<Stuff> stuff
);
```

Also, make sure that `Mix` and `Stuff` have JAXB annotations.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that this posting is not correct, at least in CXF. Note that since we're talking about the params, we're talking JAX-WS, not JAXB. JAX-WS will handle arrays, and there's absolutely no requirements to have any JAXB annotations on POJO's used as parameters or return values.